# Custom Assembly Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, attributes

I would like to know if I can define custom assembly attributes.  Existing attributes are defined in the following way:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyApplication")]  
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("This application is a sample application.")]  
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © MyCompany 2009")]
```

Is there a way I can do the following:

```
[assembly: MyCustomAssemblyAttribute("Hello World! This is a custom attribute.")]
```

Comment: For anyone curious, `AssemblyTitle` etc is located in `assemblyattributes.cs`. Here's the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assemblyattributes.cs.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes you can. We do this kind of thing.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute {
    string someText;
    public MyCustomAttribute() : this(string.Empty) {}
    public MyCustomAttribute(string txt) { someText = txt; }
    ...
}
```

To read use this kind of linq stmt.

```
var attributes = assembly
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), false)
    .Cast<MyCustomAttribute>();
```

Comment: but how do you patch this in as a build property?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - what do you mean?

Comment: For example, a build server. To patch the build number in, you'd do something like `dotnet build -c Release /p:BuildNumber={BUILD_NUMBER}` so for something like this, I'd expect to be able to do `dotnet build -c Release /p:MyCustomAttribute=foo`

Comment: @Sinaesthetic could you figure out that how to patch it as a build property?

Comment: Add the attribute to csproj setting the param from the property in build command.
```<ItemGroup>
    <AssemblyAttribute Include="MyCustomAttribute">
      <_Parameter1>$(MyCustomAttribute)</_Parameter1>
    </AssemblyAttribute>
  </ItemGroup>```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, use AttributeTargets.Assembly:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class AssemblyAttribute : Attribute { ... }
```