# In C# how to add a new custom properties entry in File Properties dialog details tab

Tags: c#, file-properties

In my C# project, I want to create a new custom property for all my dlls and executables and want it to show in the details tab like shown here.

[image: Properties dialog details tab]

Comment: You can add custom attributes to the assembly info, refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936953/custom-assembly-attributes

Comment: I tried it but it does not show up in the details tab. I am not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Create you own class that inherits the FileDialog : public class MyDialog : FileDialog

Comment: How Windows Forms FileDialog will help show custom properties attributes? I am not sure what do you mean.

Comment: @AsherI Elaborate more on what you have done, more code might help us to give you some advice