# Put new properties in file

Tags: c#, .net, file, properties

I would like know how to add new properties in file using C#?

[image: Click here to see example of that I want to do]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37708257/993547.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? This isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the link shows an example to dll and not any file, where I can insert, delete or update property. I need to do this at runtime. do you know how to do it?