# Is there a way to identify my custom assemblies when scanning all assemblies using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have an application with multiple projects. Of course, each project create it's own dll. Then we can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().ToList()` to get all assemblies to use reflection for many reasons.

The `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` is going to scan every assembly that exists including the standard assumblies like Microsoft's or packages we pull using Nuget of other dependency management tools. What if I want to only scan only my projects dll not the others?

Is there a way to give my projects a shared type then look for that shared type? Unfortunately my projects don't have a common name schema to scan the name for something that starts-with or ends-with here.

Comment: You can do exacly what you proposed. Declare a common custom attribute and apply that to all your assemblies.

Comment: Where would I declare that at? do you have an example?

Comment: Maybe it would be possible to go for [`AssemblyInfo.CompanyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.companyname(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Just create a custom attribute type in an new assembly then reference and apply it in all you other assemblies.

Comment: @MikeA, if you pay me 500 bucks, i will let you in on the secret of how to [search Stackoverflow for useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936953/custom-assembly-attributes) ;-)

Comment: you could always strong-name them with the same key? otherwise: an assembly-level attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of built-in assembly attributes, for example `CompanyName`. Add this attribute to your assembly (or edit, usually it's already added in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file):

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("My company")]
```

Then check if company name matches:

```
static bool IsMyAssembly(Assembly asm) {
    var company = asm.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyCompanyAttribute>();
    return company != null && company.Company == "My company";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the GAC assemblies by using:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(a => !a.GlobalAssemblyCache)
```

You can add a custom attribute to each assembly and query it:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .Select(a => a.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>()).Where(attr => attr != null && attr.CustomProp == "MyValue")
```