# Read the Authors of an Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, attributes, metadata, .net-assembly

It's quite easy to read some metadata of an assembly, just load the `Assembly` and then get the custom attributes, for example:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
AssemblyTitleAttribute? attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyTitleAttribute>();
string? title = attribute?.Title;
```

You can replace the `AssemblyTitleAttribute` by a few others like `Copyright`, `Trademark`, `Description`, `Version` but I'm unable to find something for the `Authors` (this metadata can be set at the same location than the other, on the package Tab of the project's solution).

[image]

Any idea why this attribute is missing and how it would be possible to read it's value? (I'm using dotnet standard 2.1)

Comment: I right clicked my .net exe and I couldn't find authors, I also searched for it in project properties > application > assembly information, I could not find it there either

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936982/6797509

Comment: @Clint See my update (added screenshot)

Comment: @Bidou those settings are for the package and not your resulting assembly. You can't read it like that by using `Assembly`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *No* assembly `Attribute` for `Authors` neither can it be queried via *Reflection or Shell32*

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiOQJ.png) a list of *AssembyInfo* attributes and `Authors` is not one of them

As per the updated screen shot in the question, you are referring to `Project>Properties>Package` view and the fields you see here are a mixture of *AssemblyInfo* &  *Nuget Metadata Properties*

Properties such as `Copyright` and `Description` are common for both

Where as properties such as `PackageId`, `Authors`, `PackageVersion` are *Nuget Metadata properties* which cannot be queried from the assembly.
*Nuget Metadata Properties* are a  list of properties that are used as inputs to the packing process

Why do we even have *Authors* as a field in `Project>Properties>Package` ?

- It is so that it can be references by nuget.org for displaying author's name

*From* *[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#authors)* *Doc*

> **Authors:** A semicolon-separated list of packages authors, matching the profile names on nuget.org. These are displayed in the NuGet
>   Gallery on nuget.org and are used to cross-reference packages by the
>   same authors.

**References:**

[Nuget MetaData Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties)

[Setting Extended Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties):

[Custom Assembly Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936953/custom-assembly-attributes/1936982#1936982)

Comment: Ok, to be honest I don't find this mix between Nuget Package and assembly a wise idea... It's a bit confusing!